# Postgres Replication on Inherited Table

Tags: postgresql, replication, single-table-inheritance, postgres-10

I try to create a logical replication on a inherited table with Postgres 10. But if I create the subscription I get a error that the relation does not exist. Does anyone got a idea why this happen? The other way to inherited on a replicated table works fine.

Example:
1. DB with schema a has 1 Table(parent) which is inherited from a other (child) Table and one Publisher on b (parent)
2. DB with schema a has 1 Table (parent) and a Subscriber.
If I try to Create the Subscriber I get the error that "relation a does not exist"

Comment: Please provide some SQL statements to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createpublication.html

Only persistent base tables can be part of a publication. Temporary tables, unlogged tables, foreign tables, materialized views, regular views, and partitioned tables cannot be part of a publication. To replicate a partitioned table, add the individual partitions to the publication.